# Docker swarm NFS volumes,

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am playing with docker's 1.12 swarm with Orchestration! But there is one issue I am not able to find an answer to:

1. In this case if you're running a service like nginx or redis you don't worry about the data persistence,
2. But if you're running a service like a database we need data persistance so if something happens to your docker instance the master will shuttle the docker instance to one of the available nodes, by default docker doesn't move data volumes to other nodes to address this problem. We can use third party plugins like Flocker (https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker), Rexray ("https://github.com/emccode/rexray") to solve the issue.
3. But the problem with this is: when one node fails you lose the data. Flocker or Rexray does not deal with this.
4. We can solve this if we use something like NFS. I mount the same volume to across my nodes in this case we don't have to move the data between two nodes. If one of the nodes fail its need to remember the docker mount location, can we do this? If so can we achieve this with docker Swarm Built-In Orchestration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Rexray, then the data is stored outside the docker swarm nodes (in Amazon S3, Openstack Cinder, ...). So If you loose a node, you won't loose your persistent data. If your scheduler mounts a new container which needs the data on another host, it will retrieve the external volume using rexray plugin and you're ok to go.

Note: your external provider needs to allow you to perform forced detach of the volume from the now unavailable old nodes.

Comment: rexray doesn't allow to mount volume for each container replica on separate node.